# Acer liquid e600 won't start after rooting

Tags: boot, acer-z120

I have a problem with my smart phone Acer Liquid e600.

I followed a procedure to gain root access in my phone, during the procedure, the phone was restarting twice, then it shut down and couldn't start, and my PC doesn't recognize my phone anymore.

I tried to press both volume and the on/off button simultaneously for 10 seconds to start the safe mode but I failed to do that as well.

Can you show me how to do a flash or a recovery to restore my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing Volume up and power button at the same time for 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fully charge the phones. PROBABLY that will unlock your phone.
Good luck